# If a linear combination of vectors u and v produce vector b, are there also an infinite number of valid combinations?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

This problem comes from Strang's Introduction to Linear Algebra.

[Question 29 from Strang Chapter 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7O1al.png)

[Official solution to Question 29 from Strang Chapter 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omlJy.png)

It makes sense to me for three vectors if I solve them algebraically. However, it states that it works even if u = 0, which I interpret as essentially being only two vectors. How does this work? You can set up two row equations and only get back one value.

For example, taking v and w directly from the question:

$2x + y = 0$

$7x + 5y = 1$

$x = -1/3$ and $y = 2/3$

How could there be an infinite number of combinations here?

Comment: if u=0 then you can take 1*u+(linear combination of the other two) or 2*u+(lcotot) or 3*u+(lcotot), etc. thus resulting in infinitely many

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $u = 0, v+w = b$.
Then $$u+v+w = 5u+v+w = -3u+v+w = b$$ and so on. The coefficient in front of $u$ can be anything you like, so there are infinitely many possibilities.

Also - the easiest example for why you won't always have infinitely many possible combinations is $u=v=w=0$. Then any linear combination will always be zero (and never $b$).